# Create autosigned transaction approval using moralis, ethers and metamask

Tags: javascript, reactjs, metamask, ethers.js, moralis

I’m using metamask as web3provider. Have this code, that returns a token’s abi:

```
import abiErc20 from './abi-erc20.json'
import { ethers } from "ethers"

const abiObj = {
    erc20abi: (tokenForAbi) => {
        const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
        const signer = provider.getSigner()
        const contract = new ethers.Contract(tokenForAbi, abiErc20, signer)
        return contract
    },
    methods: {
        allowance: async (abi, wallet, router) => {
            const res = await abi.allowance(wallet, router)
            console.log('Allowance : ', res)
            return res
        },
        balance: async (abi, wallet) => {
            const res = await abi.balanceOf(wallet)
            console.log('Balance : ', res)
            return res
        },
        approve: async (abi, router, amount) => {
            const res = await abi.approve(router, amount)
            console.log('Approve : ', res)
            return res
        }
    }
}

export default abiObj
```

And this part code, for call functions:

```
async function Approve() {
      const abiFrom = abiObj.erc20abi('0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c')
      console.log('AbiFrom: ', abiFrom)
      setAbiFrom(abiFrom)
      const allowanceChecked = await abiObj.methods.allowance(abiFrom, userAddress, exchangeAddresses.pancakeAddress)
      const fromBalance = await abiObj.methods.balance(abiFrom, userAddress)
      const fromApprove = await abiObj.methods.approve(abiFrom, '0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c', '100', userAddress)
    }
```

Is there any way I can auto-sign the transaction approval, without the metamask pop-up?

Looked up [docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/), but not find anithing helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cant. A transaction should be signed by user unless it is possible call approve inside your smart contract itself.